# Why docker build . command is not working?

Tags: docker

I have docker installed.

I navigate to my project on git bash (windows) and type docker build .

and following error occurs:

error during connect:  This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running. open //./pipe/docker_engine: The specified file could not be found.

So I did some reaseach, did all steps from Windows Manual installation steps for older versions of WSL(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual) but it seems like I have already met all of requirements

and the problem still occurs.

Comment: It looks like Docker doesnt run. Make sure it was installed properly and it get started